# ¿Cómo subir varias imagenes al servidor y a la base de datos con php?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este pequeño script que lo que hace es subir 1 o varias imágenes al servidor y guardar el nombre de la misma en la BD en su campo correspondiente.

El problema que tengo es que cuando subo 2 o 3 imágenes, en la BD se duplica o triplica (depende del número de imágenes que suba) el mismo registro y no sé el motivo.

Este es el script en php y el formulario:

```
<?
include("conectar.php");

//aqui van las imagenes (Carpeta o ruta que usaras)
$path = "http://url.es/img/";

//Hacemos un poco de código verificando que se recibieron las imagenes
if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){

    //almacenamos las propiedades de las imagenes
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];

    //recorremos el array de imagenes para subirlas al simultaneo
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "img/".$name_array[$i])){

            //guardamos en la base de datos el nombre
            $act = "INSERT INTO productos (foto1,foto2,foto3) values ('$name_array[0]','$name_array[1]','$name_array[2]')";
            if(@mysql_query($act)){echo "<img src='".$path.$name_array[$i]."'> Se ha subido exitosamente.<br>";

        }
        else
        {
            //si ocurrio algun problema entonces
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
}}
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p align="center">Fotos:</p>

<input name="file_array[]" type="file" multiple>

<input name="enviar" type="submit" value="Guardar" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en el `count($tmp_name_array)` y es obvio: Si hay 3 fotos el ciclo `for` itera 3 veces y ejecuta la sentencia 3 veces. Debes eliminar ese ciclo. Por otro lado es conveniente que generes una tabla intermedia en tu base de datos llamada "fotos_usuarios" o algo asi y que enlaces con el id de usuario. Con una tabla como esa podrías hacer algo así como:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){

    //almacenamos las propiedades de las imagenes
    $name_array     = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array     = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array     = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array    = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
    $id_usuarios    = $_POST["id_usuario"]

    //recorremos el array de imagenes para subirlas al simultaneo
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "img/".$name_array[$i])){

            //guardamos en la base de datos el nombre
            $act = "INSERT INTO fotos_usuarios (id_usuario, foto, url) values ($id_usuario, '$name_array[$i]','$path.$name_array[$i]')";
            if(@mysql_query($act)){echo "<img src='".$path.$name_array[$i]."'> Se ha subido exitosamente.<br>";

        }
        else
        {
            //si ocurre algún problema 
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
}}
```

Nota: No es un código optimo pero para no desarmar el ejemplo.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, gracias por tu respuesta, lo que me interesa entonces es eliminar el for para solucionarlo, lo he intentado eliminando `for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){  }` y los `[$i]`, no sé si lo he hecho bien porque estoy aprendiendo y no sé mucho, pero ahora me da error en la fila que contiene `if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array, "img/".$name_array)){`

Comment: Porque  no le estas poniendo el índice a los array $tmp_name_array y $name_array, solo sus nombres. Puedes dejar el for como estaba para hacer esa parte, pero saca la consulta del ciclo. E insisto en lo de la tabla y el usuario @Javier Solis Guzman también te sugiere lo mismo según leí en su respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estás leyendo directamente hasta 3 entradas que pueden existir para los nombres de los archivos, según se muestra en estas línea:

```
$act = "INSERT INTO productos (foto1,foto2,foto3) values ('$name_array[0]','$name_array[1]','$name_array[2]')";
if (@mysql_query($act)) { ... }
```

Pero esta operación, a su vez, está dentro de un ciclo `for`:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++) {
    //...
    $act = "INSERT INTO ... ";
    //...
}
```

Te recomiendo que utilices solo la sentencia, sin el ciclo `for`. O que trates cada imagen como una fila en tu tabla y registres imagen por imagen en un solo registro, así utilizando el ciclo `for` y la entrada actual de dicho elemento en el arreglo.

Comment: Hola Luiggi, gracias por tu respuesta, lo que me interesa entonces es eliminar el "for" para solucionarlo, lo he intentado eliminando `for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){  }` y los `[$i]`, no sé si lo he hecho bien porque estoy aprendiendo y no sé mucho, pero ahora me da error en la fila que contiene `if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array, "img/".$name_array)){`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en el ciclo for, si envias una sola imagen no hay problema porque solo entra una vez al ciclo el problema es cuando subes mas de una, la instrucion que esta dentro del ciclo, que es la que inserta a la base de datos se ejecuta varias veces, es por eso que cuando tu envias 3 imagenes se hacen 3 inserciones de las mismas imagenes, la solucion seria quitar el ciclo for.

En mi opinion el problema mas grande es que estas predefiniendo el numero de imagenes que tendras, tal vez sea necesario para tu aplicacion pero si no fuera asi deberias crear la tabla productos_imagenes la cual tendra como atributos id_producto, nombre_imagen y algun otro dato que quiseras, logrando asi que un producto tenga de 0 a n numero de imagenes.

Answer (score 0):

Como dijeron otros el problema esta en el FOR, no se entiende bien porque iteras así pero te dejo algo que quizás te sirva para orientarte y es un poco mas genérico..

```
if($_FILES){
  foreach($_FILES as $imagen => $value){
    if($value['error'] == 0){
      if(is_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'])){
        $tmpNombreImagen = explode(".", $value["name"]);
        $nombreImagen = $_POST['nombreImagen'] ."_".$imagen.".". end($tmpNombreImagen);
        move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'], "../imagenes_pre_inscripcion/$nombreImagen");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tenes que tener en mente que dentro de $_FILES tenes toda la data de todas las imágenes, para hacer un poquito de debug y entender lo que te digo podes verlo con la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Al verlo te vas a dar cuenta de la estructura del array rápidamente, con eso, si sabes como armar el bucle correctamente vas a poder solucionarlo rápido! =)

En base la estructura que adjuntas quizás te conviene comenzar a armar **query** "ANTES" del **bucle** y finalizarla "LUEGO/DENTRO" anidando las cadenas =).

Espero te sirva,

Saludos,