# ¿Como subir multiples imagenes al servidor en una carpeta espesifica con PHP?

Tags: php, html

Quiero desde un formulario poder subir varias imagenes al tiempo, que sea enviado por post, que en subir.php este el formulario y que en proceso.php sea enviado el formulario de tal manera que pueda almacenarlas en una carpeta espesifica.

Comment: haz probado algo? código? referencia: http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.multiple.php: y posible duplicado: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4590/c%C3%B3mo-subir-varias-imagenes-al-servidor-y-a-la-base-de-datos-con-php?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo a tu respuesta.

Página `subir.php`

```
<form method="post" action="proceso.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Subir imagen: <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Subir imágenes" />
 </form>
```

Pagina `proceso.php`

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES["file"]))
{
   $reporte = null;
     for($x=0; $x<count($_FILES["file"]["name"]); $x++)
    {
      $file = $_FILES["file"];
      $nombre = $file["name"][$x];
      $tipo = $file["type"][$x];
      $ruta_provisional = $file["tmp_name"][$x];
      $size = $file["size"][$x];
      $dimensiones = getimagesize($ruta_provisional);
      $width = $dimensiones[0];
      $height = $dimensiones[1];
      $carpeta = "tu_ruta/";

      if ($tipo != 'image/jpeg' && $tipo != 'image/jpg' && $tipo != 'image/png' && $tipo != 'image/gif')
      {
          $reporte .= "<p style='color: red'>Error $nombre, el archivo no es una imagen.</p>";
      }
      else if($size > 1024*1024)
      {
          $reporte .= "<p style='color: red'>Error $nombre, el tamaño máximo permitido es 1mb</p>";
      }
      else if($width > 500 || $height > 500)
      {
          $reporte .= "<p style='color: red'>Error $nombre, la anchura y la altura máxima permitida es de 500px</p>";
      }
      else if($width < 60 || $height < 60)
      {
          $reporte .= "<p style='color: red'>Error $nombre, la anchura y la altura mínima permitida es de 60px</p>";
      }
      else
      {
          $src = $carpeta.$nombre;

          //Caragamos imagenes al servidor
          move_uploaded_file($ruta_provisional, $src);       

          //Codigo para insertar imagenes a tu Base de datos.
          //Sentencia SQL

          echo "<p style='color: blue'>La imagen $nombre ha sido subida con éxito</p>";
      }
    }

    echo $reporte;
}
```