# Como puedo subir múltiples imágenes a una base de datos?

Tags: html, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, formularios, imagen

Como puedo subir imagenes desde mi formulario a una base de datos en phpmyadmin, quiero subir varias imagenes al mismo tiempo a una base de datos para tener guardada la ubicacion y que las imagenes se guarden en una carpeta para la ubicacion pero no se si sea posible y no se como hacerlo, me podrian ayudar?
Mi formulario seria asi:

```html
<form action="php/new.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return new();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="uploads[]" accept="image/*" multiple>
 <input type="submit" class="main_button" name="submint" value="Añadir producto" style="padding: 5px;"><br><br>
```

mi base de datos es basicamente tine su id y la columna donde quiero guardar la ubicacion con el nombre de uploads.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO español :D, a que te refieres con guardar la ubicación?
a la ubicación de la información exif que te proporciona la imagen?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como subir multiples imagenes al servidor en una carpeta espesifica con PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31141/como-subir-multiples-imagenes-al-servidor-en-una-carpeta-espesifica-con-php)