# Error al subir archivos mediante PHP

Tags: php, file, upload

Haga lo que haga siempre me sale el error:

```
//echo "Ha ocurrido un error. Inténtelo de nuevo...";
```

Y sí, tengo el Xampp encendido con el Apache y MySQL.

**Código HTML:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="anadir_cabana" id="anadir_cabana" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar_formulario_cabana();">
<label for="imagen">Imagen:</label>
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="imagen[]" required /> 
</form>
```

**Código PHP:**

```
   //Subir el nombre de una imagen. $_FILES: Variables de subida de ficheros HTTP.
        if (!isset($_FILES["imagen"]) || $_FILES["imagen"]["error"] > 0){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Ha ocurrido un error. Inténtelo de nuevo...');</script>";
            //echo "Ha ocurrido un error. Inténtelo de nuevo...";
        }else{
            $cantidad=count($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]);
                for ($i=0; $i<$cantidad; $i++){
                //Comprobamos si la extensión el fichero es de tipo imagen y menor de 16MB.
                $permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
                $limite_kb = 16384;
                //Si la extensión del fichero a subir, coincide con la de permitidos...
                if (in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'][$i], $permitidos) && $_FILES['imagen']['size'][$i] <= $limite_kb * 1024){
                    //Guardamos la imagen como archivo local en "$imagen_temporal". [tmp_name] sería para archivo temporal (carpeta tmp de Xampp).
                    $imagen_temporal = $_FILES['imagen']['name'][$i];

                    //Tipo de extensión.
                    $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'][$i];

                    //Escapamos los caracteres para que se puedan almacenar en la base de datos correctamente.
                    //$imagen_temporal = mysql_escape_string($imagen_temporal);
                    $ruta_imagen = $imagen_temporal; 

                    //Insertamos en la base de datos.
                    $sql = BD::anadirImagenCabana($ruta_imagen, $idcabana);
                }else{
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Formato de archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño límite de $limite_kb Kbytes.');</script>";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola! ¿Podrías poner todo el código de tu form?

Comment: @kacospro Veo innecesario colocar el código completo del FORM debido a que hay muchas más cosas y el resto sí funcionan, el action está sobre sí mismo... el resto funciona pero el tema de las imagenes no...

Comment: Lo que pasa que si omitiste algo en la tag de la form puede que no te esté llegando la imagen, así que si es necesario. En todo caso necesito saber si estás agregando correctamente el tipo de codificación

Comment: @JackNavaRow Si subo una sola imagen, sí lo sube pero si son varias no. Añadi en la pregunta edicción con el <form> que tengo.

Comment: creo que tu validacion antes de enviar esta mala, porque no veo un error (a nivel visual)

Comment: En esta respuesta puedes encontrar la solucion https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4592

Comment: Cuando subes varias imágenes `$_FILES` se convierte en un arreglo por lo que `!isset($_FILES["imagen"])` es verdadera

Comment: Entonces @kacospro ¿Cuál sería la solución? Plantéala como respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al subir varios archivos la variable `$_FILES` se convierte en un arreglo por lo que la validación `!isset($_FILES["imagen"])` siempre será verdadera. Hay varias formas de resolver tu duda, en [este ejemplo](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-424) en la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php) sugieren lo siguiente

```
foreach ($_FILES["imágenes"]["error"] as $clave => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $nombre_tmp = $_FILES["imágenes"]["tmp_name"][$clave];
        // basename() puede evitar ataques de denegació del sistema de ficheros;
        // podría ser apropiado más validación/saneamiento del nombre de fichero
        $nombre = basename($_FILES["imágenes"]["name"][$clave]);
        move_uploaded_file($nombre_tmp, "datos/$nombre");
    }
}
```

Para tu caso en especifico podríamos hacer una validación previa

```
$todoBien = true;
foreach ($_FILES["imagen"]["error"] as $clave => $error) {
    if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $todoBien = false
    }
}

if ($todoBien) {
    foreach ($_FILES["imagen"]["error"] as $clave => $error) {
        //Comprobamos si la extensión el fichero es de tipo imagen y menor de 16MB.
        $permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
        $limite_kb = 16384;
        //Si la extensión del fichero a subir, coincide con la de permitidos...
        if (in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'][$clave], $permitidos) && $_FILES['imagen']['size'][$clave] <= $limite_kb * 1024){
            //Guardamos la imagen como archivo local en "$imagen_temporal". [tmp_name] sería para archivo temporal (carpeta tmp de Xampp).
            $imagen_temporal = $_FILES['imagen']['name'][$clave];

            //Tipo de extensión.
            $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'][$clave];

            //Escapamos los caracteres para que se puedan almacenar en la base de datos correctamente.
            //$imagen_temporal = mysql_escape_string($imagen_temporal);
            $ruta_imagen = $imagen_temporal; 

            //Insertamos en la base de datos.
            $sql = BD::anadirImagenCabana($ruta_imagen, $idcabana);
        }else{
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Formato de archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño límite de $limite_kb Kbytes.');</script>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Ha ocurrido un error. Inténtelo de nuevo...');</script>";
}
```

Cabe recalcar que muchas veces no es suficiente con validar la extensión del fichero, puedes utilizar [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.getimagesize.php) para poder realizar una validación mas específica

Como dije hay varias formas de solucionar el problema, esta es solo una de ellas

Comment: Para el tamaño utilizo $_FILES['imagen']['size'][$clave] <= $limite_kb * 1024.

Comment: Si, yo me refería mas a una medida "extra" de seguridad para que no te puedan subir archivos maliciosos a tu servidor, ya que se puede modificar la extensión de un archivo facilmente y subirlo sin problema haciendolo pasar por imagen